# String output in kibana 4 scripted field

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

Is there any way to do scripted field to return a string value? Currently kibana documentations says only number scripted fields are allowed.

**example:** I am having field `A = 1` and i want my required field `B = "Foo 1"`.

Comment: Not yet supported, "we're working hard to bring in support for strings, dates, and more." https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-4-rc1-is-now-available

Comment: Thanks @Saad .. Any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Kibana4, it doesn't support non-numeric fields. If you require non-numeric scripted field, you can still you elastic search scripted field instead kibana scripted field.

But the downside is you have to reindex your ES.

Comment: That's a shame. I am using Kibana 4 to search its own definitions, such as visualizations. I wanted to add a "visType" column to the search results table that would contain the value of the type property that is nested in the visState field. I anticipated being able to create a scripted field to do this (`_source.visState.type`) but, nope, as you say, you can't do that in Kibana 4. Perhaps I'm overcautious, but I'm not keen on reindexing the Kibana 4 index (.kibana).